# VBA Wait for refresh of power query to execute next line of code

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery

I am working on a VBA project, that requires update of a specific table via power query as part of the code.
The code power query refresh needs to finish, before the query continues, but, i have not managed to find a solution to do that yet.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1


Public Sub LoadProductsForecast()
```

I have inserted a couple steps to optimise performance

```
'Deactivate global application parameters to optimise code performance
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False


'Dimensions used in code for sheets etc.
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim NoRowsInitial As Integer


''''''''''''''''''''''
''Get product data, and copy index match formula to look up the forecast

' find number of rows to use for clearing
NoRowsInitial = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Monthly Forecast").Range("D4:D15000"))

'Selecting Worksheet w. product master data
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Products")
wb.Activate
ws.Select
```

The next line is where I wish to refresh the power query, and the refresh part works as it should.
However, it countinues to run the next VBA code. I have searched for different answers online, and some refer to "DoEvents", however, it does not seem to make a difference.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - tblAdjustments").Refresh
DoEvents
```

Below, is the remaining code that should run after the PowerQuery has refreshed the table:

```
'Calculating number of rows to copy
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Products").Range("B4:B15000"))

'Copying rows
Worksheets("Products").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(lastrow + 3, 10)).Copy

'Selecring forecast sheet
Set ws = Sheets("Monthly Forecast")
ws.Select

'Disabling alerts, so pop up for pasting data does not show (activated again later)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Pasting product master data
Worksheets("Monthly Forecast").Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(lastrow, 12)).PasteSpecial


'Creating a string that contains range to paste formula in to
Dim RangeString As String
RangeString = "N8:W" & lastrow + 7

'Copying formula to paste
    Range("AJ2:AJ3").Select
    Selection.Copy

'Pasting formula that looks up baseline FC (both seasonal and SES)
    Range(RangeString).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Calculate

With Range(RangeString)
    .Value = .Value
End With

'Activating alerts again
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



''''''''''''''''''''''
''Code to clean the rows that are not used
'Remove unescessary rows


Dim NPIProducts As Integer
NPIProducts = [tblNewProd].Rows.Count


'tbl.Range.Rows.Count



Dim RowsToDelete As String

RowsToDelete = lastrow + NPIProducts * 2 & ":" & NoRowsInitial

If Left(RowsToDelete, 1) = "-" Then
    'do nothing (negative)
Else
    [tblMonthly].Rows(RowsToDelete).Delete
End If


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''End of main code

'Activate global application parameters again
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True


'Messages end user that the calculation is done
MsgBox "Load of products and forecast finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: if you truely just need the vba to wait for a bit while the query refreshes, you could try a simple call to the Application's `wait` method. For example, putting this right below your query refresh line would cause the code to wait for 10 seconds: `Call Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))`

Comment: I need it to be dynamic, as the query will need to run often, and amount of data (thus data refresh time) will vary a lot.

Comment: is your connection either an OLEDB or ODBC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your connection is OLEDB or ODBC you can set the background refresh temporarily to false - forcing the refresh to happen before code can continue on. Instead of calling

`.Connections("Query - tblAdjustments").Refresh`

do something like this:

```
Dim bRfresh As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - tblAdjustments").OLEDBConnection
        bRfresh = .BackgroundQuery
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        .BackgroundQuery = bRfresh

    End With
```

this example assumes you have an OLEDB connection. If you had ODBC, just replace `OLEDBConnection` with `ODBCConnection`

Comment: When Power Query loads data into a table in Excel it does so by setting up an OLE DB connection between itself and the table. So as a general rule for working with Power Query refreshes and macros, this is how you want to handle it.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't already, disable background refresh for the query (plus any queries that precede that query in the evaluation chain).

You'll want to make sure that the background refresh option is not ticked. I accessed this window by right-clicking the query and then clicking `Properties`. I think in some other Excel versions, you might instead need to go to `Data > Connections`, find the query in the list and then edit its properties there.

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what unchecking the box will do tho. If I'm running vba and then set code to ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll, uncheck the enable background refresh, will that solve the issue of allowing the refresh to complete first and the continue executing rest of vba code?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but in theory it should work.
Split your code in two parts.

The first part ends with the refresh.

```
sub some_sub()  
    'Deactivate global application parameters to optimise code performance
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False


    'Dimensions used in code for sheets etc.
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim NoRowsInitial As Integer


    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''Get product data, and copy index match formula to look up the forecast

    ' find number of rows to use for clearing
    NoRowsInitial = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Monthly Forecast").Range("D4:D15000"))

    'Selecting Worksheet w. product master data
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Products")
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - tblAdjustments").Refresh
end sub
```

Then in order to wait for it to finnish we let the sub run to end.

Then we let Excel fire the Worksheet_Change.
On the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


 'Calculating number of rows to copy
    lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Products").Range("B4:B15000"))

    'Copying rows
    Worksheets("Products").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(lastrow + 3, 10)).Copy

    'Selecring forecast sheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Monthly Forecast")
    ws.Select

    'Disabling alerts, so pop up for pasting data does not show (activated again later)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Pasting product master data
    Worksheets("Monthly Forecast").Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(lastrow, 12)).PasteSpecial


    'Creating a string that contains range to paste formula in to
    Dim RangeString As String
    RangeString = "N8:W" & lastrow + 7

    'Copying formula to paste
        Range("AJ2:AJ3").Select
        Selection.Copy

    'Pasting formula that looks up baseline FC (both seasonal and SES)
        Range(RangeString).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Calculate

    With Range(RangeString)
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Activating alerts again
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''Code to clean the rows that are not used
    'Remove unescessary rows


    Dim NPIProducts As Integer
    NPIProducts = [tblNewProd].Rows.Count


    'tbl.Range.Rows.Count



    Dim RowsToDelete As String

    RowsToDelete = lastrow + NPIProducts * 2 & ":" & NoRowsInitial

    If Left(RowsToDelete, 1) = "-" Then
        'do nothing (negative)
    Else
        [tblMonthly].Rows(RowsToDelete).Delete
    End If


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''End of main code

    'Activate global application parameters again
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True


    'Messages end user that the calculation is done
    MsgBox "Load of products and forecast finished"
End Sub
```

You can use Target to not make it run if you don't want to. I assume there is at least one cell that you know will change. Set the target there.